# Uploading a scaled image (thumbnail) into database - PHP

Tags: php, image, gd, scaling

I am making a simple web app that allows the owner of a store to add items to his inventory and view a list of all the items and their information (including a picture of the item) in a table. The pictures uploaded of the item are generally large. I managed to scale the picture down and output it onto the page in the code below, but I want to save the scaled image, upload it to a directory of my choosing. Here is my code so far:

```
<?php

include'connect.php';

if( isset($_POST['item_name']) && isset($_POST['description']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['quantity']) && isset($_POST['manufacturer']) && isset($_FILES['pic']['name']) )
{
    $name = $_FILES['pic']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'];

    if(!empty($_POST['item_name']) && !empty($_POST['description']) &&  !empty($_POST['price']) && !empty($_POST['quantity']) && !empty($_POST['manufacturer']) &&  !empty($name) )
    {   
        $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
        $price = $_POST['price'];
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
        $manufacturer = (int) $_POST['manufacturer'];

        $image = $_POST['pic'];
        $image_size = getimagesize($image);
        $image_width = $image_size[0];
        $image_height = $image_size[1];

        $new_size = ($image_width + $image_height) / ($image_width * ($image_height / 45));
        $new_width = $image_width * $new_size;
        $new_height = $image_height * $new_size;

        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
        $old_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);

        imagecopyresized($new_image, $old_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $image_width, $image_height );

        $location = 'Upload/';
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name);

        $query = "INSERT INTO `item` VALUES ('$item_name', '$description','$price','$quantity','$name','$manufacturer', '')";

        if($query_run = mysql_query($query))
        {   echo 'Item successfully added.';    }


    }
}

?>

<form  action = 'additems.php' method = 'POST' enctype = 'multipart/form-data' >
    Name: <input type = 'text' name = 'item_name' ><br><br>
    Description: <input type = 'text' name = 'description' ><br><br>
    Price: <input type = 'text' name = 'price' ><br><br>
    Quantity: <input type = 'text' name = 'quantity' ><br><br>
    Manufacturer: <select name = 'manufacturer' >
                  <option value = '1'> Manufacturer 1 </option>
                  <option value = '2'> Manufacturer 2 </option>
                  <option value = '3'> Manufacturer 3 </option>
                  <option value = '4'> Manufacturer 4 </option>
                  </select>
                  <br><br>
    Picture: <input type = 'file' name = 'pic' > <br><br>

    <input type = 'submit' value = 'Submit' >

</form>
```

NOTE: The SQL statement in the $query variable is how I stored the normal sized image.

Comment: _“upload it to a directory of my choosing”_ – so to the file system, and not to the database as the title suggest? Well, `imagejpeg` has a second parameter.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading title. I want to upload the NEW picture to a folder which I have created and named "Upload". Once it's in that folder, I want to retrieve its name and put it in the database.

Comment: Well, then refer to the second part of my previous comment.